# How to prevent form in InfoPath duplicating due to ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, infopath

I have created a form which is being used as a read-only web part for my company's SharePoint. I have found that the form duplicates due to having 3 separate IDs: 22, 5 which actually shows the completed fields as per the document set properties and 18. Both 18 & 22 are completely empty.

Is there a way I can single out the ID 5 and just have that form showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out.

The form reads the ID of the document set itself as well as any files or folders in the set. Now to work out how to get the form to read one ID only

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve only one ID from a list you can set up a data connection to the list you wish to pull information from, create a rule that runs when the form loads--> sets the **queryfield**-->id to whatever number you want

[image: queryfield example]

--> then add the action to query that same data connection.

Then any fields that you use on the form that are pulling data from that connection will only display information from the id you specified.

[image: form load rule example]

**Alternatively**, if you want to display information *only* from the active form you can set up a data connection to the same document library that the form is being saved and set it to only include data for the active form only:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if this can work per document set?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to display on your form, but it should work the same since all this is doing is filtering by whatever field you tell it. You might have to figure exactly which field you'd need to use as the filter: Document ID Value or ID.

Comment: I am currently trying to award each document set with a unique ID which I will base the form off. The issue I am currently having now is to do with workflow. I am, as per your username, getting well and truly pwned by SharePoint

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't each document set already have a unique ID? I think you can just use the ID or Document ID fields.

Comment: This is what I am trying to isolate so that only the document set properties are represented by the form

Comment: If you follow the directions from the first part of my answer you'll  be able to isolate any document set you want. If you need clarification on any of the steps, please let me know.